# Implement & Add a custom polyfill to my React App

Tags: reactjs, npm, polyfills

I want to add this polyfill https://github.com/brettdewoody/polyfill-nodelist-foreach to my React app.

But **I don't want to have a npm dependency on this modul**e for just 3 lines of code.

```
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
  NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```

How can I add the polyfill in a React app and have it used everywhere ?

I tried as a component but I would need to import it in every .jsx and used it explicitly while it works with just : `import 'nodelist-foreach-polyfill';` in my app/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it's enough to run the code once at the beginning of the app run time.

In my app/index.js, I thus drop the following lines and it works perfectly.

```
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```

Later I will update my babel/Core-js to get their polyfill.